# Calculating probability of event on 1st, 2nd, 3rd attempt with known success rate. TY!

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to calculate a probability of the event (successful outcome of treatment) which would happened after first, second and third trial (attempt of treatment). Success rate is a known value. Based on this how to determine mean value of the trials (specific for a given population group) required to achieve a positive outcome (result of treatment)?

For instance:
Pregnancy rate (PR) is 40%, what would be the probability to achieve a pregnancy after 1st, 2nd and 3rd attempt of treatment. While clinically attempts (events) would be dependent, I think it would be beneficial to see a solution of the problem both ways for dependent and independent trials/events. Let's say if a patient changing clinic or a provider.

With my calculation I get lower probability of event (pregnancy) with each attempt (trial), while in real clinical setting you will have a higher probability with each additional attempt. So, something is not clicking for me.

I'll appreciate any help in tackling this.

Thank you! 
PZ

Comment: Not following.  Why would clinical probabilities increase?  I would have thought that failure on the first attempt was evidence of a problem of some sort and that therefore the probability would decrease.  Conversely, why do you say the theoretical probability declines?  If you are assuming independence that ought to mean that the probability is constant on each attempt.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Attempt of treatment is already evidence of an existing problem. After treatment patient is back on track to achieve a positive outcome. With each additional attempt probability would increase. Most likely theoretical probability declines due to my miscalculation. That is why I seek for assistance in solving it :)

Comment: I am looking at your pregnancy example, the only example you provide.  In that case, I'd have thought that failure to conceive on the first try was evidence (albeit, weak evidence) of an underlying problem so clinical probabilities would decrease.  I think this is obvious, no?

Comment: The problem may be in how you are phrasing things. Certainly the probability of success by the second treatment is higher than the probability of success by the first treatment. However, it may be the case that the probability that the first treatment is successful is higher than the probability that the second treatment is the first time it is successful. Showing your calculations would really help us answer your question, though.

Comment: Take a caricature example:  suppose $40\%$ of women conceive on every attempt but $60\%$ can never conceive.  Then it is certainly true that a random trial has a $40\%$ success rate.  But failure to succeed on the first trial would, in this case, cause the probability to go to $0$ on the second as you would know that your patient was in the $60\%$ group.  Of course, the real life groupings are not so clear cut but the effect should be the same.

Comment: @lulu I'll try get into more details with my example:
1-By default every patient has a chance to conceive when they go into treatment. 2-The reported success rate is 40%, which doesn't mean that the other 60% can never conceive. 3-The remaining 60% of patients which didn't conceive after first attempt would have again a 40% to conceive on a second attempt and so on. QS: how the probability to conceive would change on every attempt? how many attempts it will take to conceive? Hope it helps.

Comment: Still not clear, sorry.  I understand that my caricature example is unrealistic, but it is still informative.  To take a more realistic model that illustrates my point, assume that each woman has her own probability of conception $p_i$ which is constant over time.  These then average out to $.4$, in your example.  Now, observing that a given woman fails to conceive on one try is evidence for the hypothesis that $p_i$ was low for her.  Thus, if my prior was that her $p_i=.4$ I would now re-estimate to assume that her $p_i$ was $<.4$ and so on.

Comment: I should say:  it occurs to me that I may be talking about a more complex situation than you actually care about.  If all you are asking is "if I have a coin that comes up $H$ with probability $.4$, then what is the probability distribution for the first occurrence of $H$?" then the answer is [the Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).  I repeat, however that I, for one don't think that's a very realistic model.